# keep track of friends and number of days not spoken to, dynamic memory location

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

The program I am trying to write is; 
Write a program that lets users keep track of the last time they talked to each of their friends. Users should be able to add new friends (as many as they want!) and store the number of days ago that they last talked to each friend. Let users update this value (but don't let them put in bogus numbers like negative values). Make it possible to display the list sorted by the names of the friends of by how recently it was since they talked to each friend.

Below is the code I have written so far. Not really sure how to progress.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct User {
    string name;
    int noDays;
};

int *growArray (int * friends, int * size) {
    *size *= 2;
    int *new_friends = new int[*size];
    for (int i=0; i < *size; i++) {
        new_friends[i] = friends[i];
    }
    delete [] friends;
    return new_friends;
}

int main()
{

    User user;
    int control;
    int next_element = 0;
    int size = 10;
    int *friends = new int[size];

        if (size == next_element+1) {
            friends = growArray(friends, &size);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter your friends name" << endl;
        cin >> user.name;
        cout << "Please enter no of days you last spoke to them" << endl;
        cin >> user.noDays;
        next_element++;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you have a question?

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Stack Overflow is meant for clearly defined questions which other people can benefit from in the future.

Comment: Yes sorry my problem is the if statement. I am getting an error saying cannot convert User* to int*. Not sure what this means

Comment: What do you think it means? What is a `User *`, and what is a `int *`, and how does that correspond to your code - in particular if you look at the line of the error.

Comment: have edited the code, I changed the user* to an integer. But am still confused as to how to get the growArray function to work properly

Comment: Don't use C-style arrays. C++ has `std::vector`, use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrote this code above, you may be able to refer to it (//for changed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct User {
    string name;
    int noDays;
};
//Note: Return Types
User *growArray (User * friends, int * size) {
    //cout << "into growArray()\n";
    User *new_friends = new User[*size * 2];
    for (int i=0; i < *size; i++) {
        new_friends[i].name = friends[i].name;
        new_friends[i].noDays = friends[i].noDays;
    }
    *size *= 2; //Place here
    delete [] friends;
    return new_friends;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    int next_element = 0;
    //struct array
    User *friends = new User[size]; 
    //use while instead of for
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter your friend's name (or q to exit):" << endl;
        cin >> friends[next_element].name;
        if (friends[next_element].name == "q")
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Please enter no of days you last spoke to them:" << endl;
        cin >> friends[next_element].noDays;
        if (size == ++next_element)
        {   
            //Return Types
            friends = growArray(friends, &size);
        }
    }
    //print result
    cout << "Do you want to print this list? (Y/N)";
    string choice;
    if (((cin >> choice) == "Y") || choice =="y")
    {
        cout << "List:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < next_element; i++)
        {
            cout << friends[i].name << '\t' << friends[i].noDays << '\n';
        }   
    }
    //delete
    delete [] friends;
    return 0;   
}
```